# No puedo alinear divs con flexbox horizontalmente,

Tags: css, flexbox

```
       <style>

            .container {
                width: 100%;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
            }

            .container .court {
                width: 50%;
                float: right;
            }
            
            .container .inputs {
                width: 30%;
            }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Controle su eficiencia de tiro</h1>
<div class="container">

    <div class="court">
        <img src="./assets/basketballhalfcourtlines_512x.webp" alt="Cancha de basket" >
    </div>

    <div class="inputs">
        <form>
            <input id="freeThrow" type="number"><label for="freeThrow"> -- %</label><br>
            <input id="leftCorner" type="number"><label for="leftCorner"> -- %</label><br>
            <input id="leftWing" type="number"><label for="leftWing"> -- %</label><br>
            <input id="center" type="number"><label for="center"> -- %</label><br>
            <input id="rightWing" type="number"><label for="rightWing"> -- %</label><br>
            <input id="rightCorner" type="number"><label for="rightCorner"> -- %</label><br>
        </form>
    </div>
    
</div>
    
</body>
```

Buenas gente, estoy teniendo un problema con flexbox y no logro solucionarlo.
Estoy intentando alinear horizentalmente mis dos div ( .court y .inputs ), lo hago como usualmente y no entiendo porque no obtengo resultado.

Mi intencion es dejar el titulo centrado y los 2 divs alineados uno al lado del otro, dandole prioridad de espacio a la imagen que al form

Answer (score 1):

Lo lograrías usando la regla `@media`, en donde digo que si superamos el ancho de `800px`, ocurrirán las propiedades de adentro (por el `max-width`):

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 20px;
  }
  
  .container .court,
  .container .inputs {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

##### Explicación:

Primero, centro el título (que es el `h1`). Luego, a tu `container` le indico que sus elementos de adentro (la imagen y los inputs) estén direccionadas horizontalmente (en columnas) con `flex-direction: column;` y que tendrán una separación de `20px`. Y por último, a ambos elementos les indico que ocuparán todo el ancho de la pantalla (`100%`), serán flexibles y se justificarán al centro para obtener un mejor resultado.

---

##### Código:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container .court {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.container .inputs {
  width: 30%;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 20px;
  }
  
  .container .court,
  .container .inputs {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Controle su eficiencia de tiro</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="court">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png" width="250px" alt="Cancha de basket" >
  </div>
  <div class="inputs">
    <form>
      <input id="freeThrow" type="number"><label for="freeThrow"> -- %</label><br>
      <input id="leftCorner" type="number"><label for="leftCorner"> -- %</label><br>
      <input id="leftWing" type="number"><label for="leftWing"> -- %</label><br>
      <input id="center" type="number"><label for="center"> -- %</label><br>
      <input id="rightWing" type="number"><label for="rightWing"> -- %</label><br>
      <input id="rightCorner" type="number"><label for="rightCorner"> -- %</label><br>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```